# Ошибка при сравнении текста файлов Difflib

Tags: python, python-3.x, diff

Вот код:

```
def one():
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f'Starting {thread_name}')
    with open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8') as f1:
        f1_lines = f1.readlines()
        return f1_lines

def two():
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f'Starting {thread_name}')
    with open(sys.argv[2], encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        f2_lines = f2.readlines()
        return f2_lines

def three():
    if sys.argv[3] is None:
        print("2 file")
    else:
        thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
        print(f'Starting {thread_name}')
        with open(sys.argv[3], encoding='utf-8') as f3:
            f3_lines = f3.readlines()
            return f3_lines

Thread(target=one, name='thr-1').start()
Thread(target=two, name='thr-2').start()
Thread(target=three, name='thr-3').start()


def diff():
    d = Differ()
    difference = list(d.compare(one(), two(), three()))
    difference = '\n'.join(difference)
    return difference

print(diff())
```

При запуске скрипта (python3 myscript.py dir1/zlib.1.2.11.log dir2/zlib.1.2.12.log dir3/zlib.1.2.12.log) появляется ошибка "TypeError: Differ.compare() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given". Указывает на ошибку в 48 строке "difference = list(d.compare(one(), two(), three()))", как можно решить эту проблему или как иначе можно добавить для сравнения третий файл?

UPD: функцию def three() реализовал иначе, но теперь при сравнении строка первого файла остаётся неизменной, то есть при сравнении строк файлов между собой у первого файла всегда сравнивается первая строка со строками остальных файлов

```
def three():
time.sleep(1)
if len(sys.argv[3]) is None:
    print("2 file")
else:
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f'Starting {thread_name}')
    file1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    file2 = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
    file3 = open(sys.argv[3], 'r')
    i = 0
    for l1 in file1:
        for l2 in file2:
            for l3 in file3:
                if l1 == l2:
                    print("Line ", i, ": IDENTICAL")
                else:
                    print("Line ", i, ":")
                    print("File 1:", l1)
                    print("File 2:", l2)
                    print("File 3:", l3)
                break

    file1.close()
    file2.close()
    file3.close()
```

И вывод примерно следующий:

```
Line 0:
File 1: 30-06-2022 11:00:01
File 2: 30-06-2022 11:00:00
File 3: 30-06-2022 11:00:00
Lime 0:
File 1: 30-06-2022 11:00:01
File 2: 222
File 3: 33
```

Не подскажите что я сделал не так?

Comment: Судя по документации `compare` принимает только два аргумента. Ну, вернее, три, если считать `self`. Так что как-то по два нужно файлы сравнивать видимо.

Comment: Вот тут какой-то самописный метод предлагают: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623225/using-python-difflib-to-compare-more-than-two-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сравнивать строки параллельно должен помочь `zip`:

```py
    for l1,l2,l3 in zip(file1, file2, file3):
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда помогло